# Order of precedence in lexer

Tags: lexical-analysis, ocamllex

I am writing a lexer and a parser for Excel formulas.

In Excel, we could assign a cell a name. For example, `abc` is a valid name, whereas, it is forbidden to name a cell `B2` to avoid the confusion with the cell 
`B2`. So once we meet a formula `=B2`, we are sure that `B2` refers a cell rather than a user defined name.

In my `lexer_formula.mll`, I have defined identifiers:

```
let lex_cell = ['A' - 'Z']+ ['0' - '9']+ (* regular expressions to include all the cells *)
let lex_name = ['A' - 'Z' '0' - '9']+ (* regular expressions to include all the names *)
```

But a string like `B2` with match both `lex_cell` and `lex_name`, does anyone know how I could tell the lexer to consider first `lex_cell`, then `lex_name`? Will it be sufficient to put `lex_cell` before `lex_name` in `rule token = parse`?

Comment: Are you actually using ocamllex? You have a lot of tags, but you don't ever say which scanner generator you are using.

Comment: Yes, I am using `ocamllex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [ocamllex manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual026.html#htoc144), it's sufficient to put `lex_cell` first:

> If several regular expressions match a prefix of the input, the “longest match” rule applies: the regular expression that matches the longest prefix of the input is selected. In case of tie, the regular expression that occurs earlier in the rule is selected.